# How can I find this moment generating function?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I have a random variable $C$ with probability density $\frac{c}{8}$ where $0\leq c \leq 4$. I am having trouble finding the moment generating function of this distribution.

$\begin{split} M_C(t) &= E_C(e^{tc})\\ &= \int_{0}^{4}e^{tc}\frac{c}{8}\,dc\\ &= \frac{1}{8}\int_0^4e^{tc}c\,dc\end{split}$

This is as far as I can get. I think that I have to somehow manipulate the expression in the integral to become a distribution, causing the integral to evaluate to one. I will then be left with some function of $t$ on the outside of the integral.

Can anyone help me find this MGF? Anything would be much appreciated.

Comment: $\int xe^x$ is a classic intergral by parts

Comment: It equals $xe^x-e^x$ or something like that

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yes, but when I have the constant $t$, it becomes more complicated. $\int_0^4 x e^{cx}dx = \frac{(e^{4 c} (4 c - 1) + 1)}{c^2}$, which cannot be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why not? That's the correct solution… hence $$M_C(t) = \frac{e^{4 t} (4 t - 1) + 1}{8t^2}$$

Comment: @Gono It just seems far too complicated. If you look at the MGFs of gamma distribution and normal distribution they are very simple expressions. Those simple expressions aren't find just by integrating directly. Some algebraic manipulation is done to make the integral evaluate to $1$.

Comment: Funny argumentation… but still you are wrong. It is not "complicated", quite the contrary… it's never easier than just solve the integral in one step. As you already pointed out: For some MGFs some more work is to do. But happily not this time. And btw: Also e.g. for normal distribution it's "just" integration… the step that you transform the integral to get an integration to 1 is very usual for normal distribution terms. But here you don't have a normal distribution.